# Visual Studio Code - remote code execution

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-remote

I am using VSC on a Mac computer, working in a development environment that resides on a remote machine running Ubuntu 22.04. I can run my code locally on the Ubuntu computer without a problem. I have successfully connected to the Ubuntu environment using the Remote-SSH extension, and I can edit modules remotely. But when I try to run the code remotely (i.e., when I try to run the code using VSC on my Mac computer which is connected to Ubuntu using Remote-SSH) it fails.

In this instance, I am using Puppeteer to build a screenscraping tool. The code works locally on the Ubuntu machine, but doesn't run when I try to execute it remotely from my Mac. When I try I get the following error:

```
admin@ubuntu:~/repo/scraper$ node advancedSearch.js
/home/admin/repo/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262
                reject(new Error([
                       ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process! undefined
[311441:311441:0514/075305.238400:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[311441:311441:0514/075305.238431:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at ChildProcess.onClose (/home/admin/repo/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)

Node.js v19.0.0
```

How can I trigger the code to run only on the Ubuntu computer from my remote Mac computer?

Comment: Are you running puppeteer in headless mode?

Comment: @DutChen18 I’ve got headless set to false - I’ll try putting it back to true

Comment: @DutChen18 - I put puppeteer back in its default headless mode and now it work fine from a remote session. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587). usually [RCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) is a bad thing. this title is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: Sure thing @user. Sorry ‘bout that. I’ll try to be better about my titles in the future. 
Perhaps you have something in mind that’d be more appropriate; I’d love to hear one or two suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Per @DutChen18 response, it was failing because I had Puppeteer in the non-default mode to watch Puppeteer's execution of Chrome browser locally on the Ubuntu machine. Once I put Puppeteer back into it's default, headless mode, the script ran fine when executed remotely.